# How to user SkillContext to pass data from VirtualAssistant to a Skill

Tags: c#, botframework

I need to share an information from my Virtual Assistant with a Skill. I try to use SkillContext, I don't get errors but in the Skill the SkillContext is empty.

This is the code I use in the VirtualAssistant MainDialog::RouteAsync to set the payload

```cs
                Dictionary<string, JObject> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, JObject>();

                dictionary.Add("userEmail", JObject.Parse("{ email: 'emiliano.carlesi@itattitude.com'}"));

                await _skillContextAccessor.SetAsync(dc.Context, new SkillContext(dictionary));

                var result = await dc.BeginDialogAsync(identifiedSkill.Id);
```

In the Cosmos DB botstate-db I found the value:

```
        "SkillContext": {
            "$type": "Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Skills.SkillContext, Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Skills",
            "userEmail": {
                "email": "emiliano.carlesi@itattitude.com"
            }
        },
```

This is the code in MainDialog::RouteAsync I use to retrieve the payload:

```cs
            SkillContext skillContext = await _contextAccessor.GetAsync(dc.Context, () => new SkillContext());

            if (skillContext == null)
            {
                TelemetryClient.TrackTrace("skillContext is null", Severity.Information, null);
            }
            else
            {
                TelemetryClient.TrackTrace("skillContext is not null", Severity.Information, null);

                if (skillContext.Keys != null && skillContext.Keys.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (string key in skillContext.Keys)
                    {
                        TelemetryClient.TrackTrace(String.Format("Key in skillContext: {0}", key), Severity.Information, null);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Problem solved, I write this post to explain how to do: https://carlesi.vg/2019/09/03/share-data-from-virtual-assistant-to-skill/

Comment: Please write a self-contained answer containing the solution. A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).