# BotFramework: Passing data from skill to Virtual Assistant

Tags: typescript, botframework

I have 2 skills connected to a Virtual Assistant, and I am trying to invoke Skill B from Skill A (at the end of Skill A, and with no further action by the user). I know that I have to go through the Virtual assistant for that. I have two problems to handle:

- Passing data from Skill A -> VA
- Passing data from VA -> Skill B

For the 2nd problem, using the SkillContext with slots looks to be [the way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57747846/how-to-user-skillcontext-to-pass-data-from-virtualassistant-to-a-skill), but I can't seem to find a solution for the 1st problem, because when the skill returns to the VA, all it sends back is a boolean indicating whether it has completed or not https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/blob/853a7ccb940ec2c4d59433b6f2ca2cfa8d5264b4/lib/typescript/botbuilder-skills/src/skillDialog.ts#L229 .

What I have tried to do is to save my data in the SkillContext in Skill A, then get that data in the VA and pass it to Skill B. That however only works if both Skill A and the VA are writing to the same Cosmos DB, which would not be ideal.

Are there any better solutions out there?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this yet? I'm in the same situation, looking for a solution for this..

Comment: Hey @Edwin, no unfortunately, that's not supported yet, but it's something that the Microsoft dev team is working on right now https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/issues/2456

Answer (score 0):

Passing data from skill to Parent Bot with out using Dialogs can this possible?

I'm using below snippet to call skill from root bot

```
var response = await _skillClient.PostActivityAsync(_botId, targetSkill, _skillsConfig.SkillHostEndpoint, turnContext.Activity, cancellationToken);
```

I'm using below snippet to end conversation in skill bot

```
var endOfConversation = Activity.CreateEndOfConversationActivity();
endOfConversation.Code = EndOfConversationCodes.CompletedSuccessfully;
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I am using the Bot Composer rather than PVA.  I hope that the syntax is similar & that this will work for PVA with a custom created skill the same way.

I have been looking to do something similar & was able to get a workable solution using the below syntax.

In my example I have a waterfall dialog with 2 steps.  The 1st step displays a prompt with a few choices.  The last step retrieves the selected value & ends the conversation & the dialog.  In my case I want the selected value to be returned as the output of the skill so that I can save it to a variable in the composer & use it later in the conversation.

My dialog code is:

```
public class ActiveFuelCardDialog : ComponentDialog
{
    public ActiveFuelCardDialog() : base(nameof(ActiveFuelCardDialog))
    {
        InitializeWaterfallDialog();
    }

    public WaterfallStepContext StepContext { get; private set; }

    private void InitializeWaterfallDialog()
    {
        var waterFallSteps = new WaterfallStep[]
        {
            CardSelectionStepAsync,
            FinalStepAsync
        };

        AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog($"{nameof(ActiveFuelCardDialog)}.mainFlow", waterFallSteps));
        AddDialog(new ChoicePrompt($"{nameof(ActiveFuelCardDialog)}.cardSelection"));

        InitialDialogId = $"{nameof(ActiveFuelCardDialog)}.mainFlow";
    }

    private async Task<DialogTurnResult> CardSelectionStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        StepContext = stepContext;
        //then return back a list of 2 cards
        //in the format: CardType
        List<ActiveFuelCardsOutput> activeFuelCardsOutputs = new List<ActiveFuelCardsOutput>();
        activeFuelCardsOutputs.Add(new ActiveFuelCardsOutput()
        {
            CardNo = "1234567890123456",
            CardType = "WM",
            ExpiryDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(8)
        });

        activeFuelCardsOutputs.Add(new ActiveFuelCardsOutput()
        {
            CardNo = "2345678901234657",
            CardType = "WM",
            ExpiryDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(6)
        });

        activeFuelCardsOutputs.Add(new ActiveFuelCardsOutput()
        {
            CardNo = "3456789012345678",
            CardType = "WM",
            ExpiryDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(12)
        });

        return await stepContext.PromptAsync($"{nameof(ActiveFuelCardDialog)}.cardSelection",
            new PromptOptions
            {
                Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("Please select a card"),
                Choices = ChoiceFactory.ToChoices(activeFuelCardsOutputs.Select(x => x.CardNo).ToArray())
            }, cancellationToken);
    }

    private async Task<DialogTurnResult> FinalStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        StepContext = stepContext;
        string selectedCard = ((FoundChoice)stepContext.Result).Value;

        //https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/teams-developer/skill-dialog-enddialog-does-not-work/m-p/1476612
        await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(new Activity()
        {
            Type = ActivityTypes.EndOfConversation,
            Code = EndOfConversationCodes.CompletedSuccessfully,
            Value = selectedCard
        });

        return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync();
    }
}
```

The part which caused this functionality to work for me was in the FinalStepAsync method

```
            await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(new Activity()
        {
            Type = ActivityTypes.EndOfConversation,
            Code = EndOfConversationCodes.CompletedSuccessfully,
            Value = selectedCard
        });

        return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync();
```

This seems to end the conversation & return the value.

I could then use that in the Bot Composer by setting the "Property" of the Skill to some variable (such as dialog.selectedCard).  Then use the value late like "${dialog.selectedCard}".

This post lead me to this answer.
[Helpful Post](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/teams-developer/skill-dialog-enddialog-does-not-work/m-p/1476612)

[Showing Conversation calling skill & using value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhcgx.png)